# JavaScript library for XMPP chat

Tags: library, javascript, xmpp

What would be a good JavaScript library for an XMPP chat application?

We are using ejabberd as the server. We need WhatsApp-like features such as message sending and receiving, file sharing, and online-offline status checking.